# SwiftUI how to have next and back animations?

Tags: swiftui

I made sample app with 3 pages and "Next", "Back" buttons.

[image]

When I click "Next" animation is perfect: the old content goes to the left and new content comes from the right.

However, I'm struggling to make "Back" animation to work nice simultaneously.

Goal: when clicking "Back" old content should go to the right and new content should come from the left. (animation for "Back" should be reverse to animation for "Next")

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Below is perfectly working transition for "Next"

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var page: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button(action: { withAnimation() { self.page = self.page - 1 } }) {
                    Text("Back")
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button(action: { withAnimation() { self.page = self.page + 1 }}) {
                    Text("Next")
                }
            }
            Spacer()
            
            if page == 0 {
                PageView(name: "First page", color: .brown)
                    .transition(AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .trailing), removal: .move(edge: .leading)))
            } else if page == 1 {
                PageView(name: "Second page", color: .systemGreen)
                    .transition(AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .trailing), removal: .move(edge: .leading)))
            } else if page == 2 {
                PageView(name: "Third page", color: .systemBlue)
                    .transition(AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .trailing), removal: .move(edge: .leading)))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PageView: View {
    var name: String
    var color: UIColor
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Text(name)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .padding(.vertical, 50)
        .background(Color(color))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to reverse transition when navigating back.

Here is possible approach (also made transition in one place and corrected animation to work everywhere, including Preview).

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

[image: demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var page: Int = 0

    @State private var isBack = false   // << reverse flag (not animatable)
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.isBack = true
                    self.page = self.page - 1
                }) {
                    Text("Back")
                }

                Spacer()

                Button(action: {
                    self.isBack = false
                    self.page = self.page + 1
                }) {
                    Text("Next")
                }
            }
            Spacer()

            Group {
                if page == 0 {
                    PageView(name: "First page", color: .brown)
                } else if page == 1 {
                    PageView(name: "Second page", color: .systemGreen)
                } else if page == 2 {
                    PageView(name: "Third page", color: .systemBlue)
                }
            }.transition(AnyTransition.asymmetric(
                insertion:.move(edge: isBack ? .leading : .trailing),
                removal: .move(edge: isBack ? .trailing : .leading))
            )
            .animation(.default, value: self.page)   // << animate here by value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work on iOS 15

Comment: Yes, agree with previous comment. On iOS 16 if try to tap Next 3 times and then Back 3 times it works like in the video. But if I try to tap Next and then Back, then the latter animation is broken. It would be nice to get any help with the fix.

Comment: @Sander I just wrote an answer with the fix.

Comment: @paulRick yeah, just tried. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Works for me in ios 16

```
Group {
                switch viewModel.selectedTab {
                    case .travel:
                        view1
                    case .cars:
                        view2
                    case .rooms:
                        view3
                }
            }
            .transition(.dynamicSlide(forward: $viewModel.tabTransitionDirectionIsForward))
            .animation(.default, value: viewModel.selectedTab)

extension AnyTransition {
    
    struct SlideModifier: ViewModifier {
        let width: CGFloat
        @Binding var forward: Bool

        func body(content: Content) -> some View {
            content
                .offset(x: (forward ? 1 : -1) * width)
        }
    }

    static func dynamicSlide(forward: Binding<Bool>) -> AnyTransition {
        return .asymmetric(
            insertion: .modifier(
                active: SlideModifier(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, forward: forward),
                identity: SlideModifier(width: 0, forward: .constant(true))
            ),

            removal: .modifier(
                active: SlideModifier(width: -UIScreen.main.bounds.width, forward: forward),
                identity: SlideModifier(width: 0, forward: .constant(true))
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: this works great. How could you incorporate opacity into it so that the view that is sliding away fades out and the incoming view fades in?

Comment: Just add some animation after .offset(x: (forward ? 1 : -1) * width)

Comment: I tried variations of this but nothing worked.
`.opacity(forward ? 1 : 0)
.animation(.easeInOut, value: forward)`

Answer (score 1):

To fix the problem with the animation in the [@asperi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12299030/asperi) answer, just need to give some time to SwiftUI change the view after the animation state changed.

```
HStack {
Button(action: {
    self.isBack = true
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) { // <--
        self.page = self.page - 1
    }
}) {
    Text("Back")
}

Spacer()

Button(action: {
    self.isBack = false
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {  // <--
        self.page = self.page + 1
    }
}) {
    Text("Next")
}
```

}