# Change view without Navigation link SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, segue, swiftui-navigationlink

I everyone! I spent hours looking for something that I guess very simple but I can not managed to find the best way...
I have my body view :

```
var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            // The CircularMenu
            CircularMenu(menuItems: homeMenuItems, menuRadius: 55, menuButtonSize: 55, menuButtonColor: .black, buttonClickCompletion: buttonClickHandler(_:))
                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())

        }
    }
```

Which contains a circular menu. Each click on a menu item calls :

```
func buttonClickHandler(_ index: Int) {
        /// Your actions here
        
        switch index {
        //Thermometer
        case 0:
            print("0")
        //Light
        case 1:
            print("1")
        //Video
        case 2:
            print("2")
        //Alarm
        case 3:
            print("3")
        //Car
        case 4:
            self.destinationViewType = .car
            self.nextView(destination: .car)
            
        default:
            print("not found")
        }
    }
```

I want to perform a simple view transition to another view called Car. `nextView` function looks like this :

```
func nextView(destination: DestinationViewType) {
        
        switch destination {
            case .car: Car()
        }
    }
```

I thought that was simple like this but I get : `Result of 'Car' initializer is unused` on the case line.
So someone knows how to achieve that ? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63782921/12299030?

Comment: Thanks but this method use navigationlink. I do not want to use this.

Comment: At which line of code you found NavigationLink? ;)

Comment: @Silvering Does my answer for [Go to a new view using SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59592697/9607863) help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

Create a `struct` called `IdentifiableView` which contains an `AnyView` and an `id`:

```
struct IdentifiableView: Identifiable {
    let view: AnyView
    let id = UUID()
}
```

Create a `@State` var to hold the `nextView`.  Use .`fullScreenCover(item:)` to display the `nextView`

```
@State private var nextView: IdentifiableView? = nil

var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            // The CircularMenu
            CircularMenu(menuItems: homeMenuItems, menuRadius: 55, menuButtonSize: 55, menuButtonColor: .black, buttonClickCompletion: buttonClickHandler(_:))
                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())

        }.fullScreenCover(item: self.$nextView, onDismiss: { nextView = nil}) { view in
            view.view
        }
}
```

Then, assign `self.nextView` the `IdentifiableView`:

```
case .car: self.nextView = IdentifiableView(view: AnyView(Car()))
```

When it's time to return to the `MenuView` use `self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()` to dismiss the view.  Here is an example of a minimal `Car` view:

```
struct Car: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

    var body: some View {
        Text("Car View").onTapGesture {
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @vacawama. Your solution works really great!! I chose your solution as the best. Thanks a lot guys I appreciate

Answer (score 1):

If you want to completely replace the body content with the new view, you need some condition about that. Let's say you have a `Container` with a `body` and if there is a `Car` view created we will display it:

```swift
struct Container: View {

    @State var car: Car?      // Storage for optional Car view

    var body: some View {
        if let car = car {    // if the car view exists
            car               // returning the car view
        } else {              // otherwise returning the circular menu
            VStack {
                CircularMenu(menuItems: homeMenuItems, menuRadius: 55, menuButtonSize: 55, menuButtonColor: .black, buttonClickCompletion: buttonClickHandler(_:))
                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            }
        }
    }
...
```

And then we only need to assign the newly created instance of the car view on click:

```swift
...
    func buttonClickHandler(_ index: Int) {
        switch index {
        ....
        //Car
        case 4:
        car = Car()         // assigning the newly created instance
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

I see that you have mentioning of `destinationViewTyp` and some other cases. So your code will be slightly more complex than this, but the idea keeps the same. We store either a view or some information that helps us create a view when necessary and then returning either a picker or a view depending on condition.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Denis. Your solution works really Great!