# Button action to second screen

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How can I do a Button action -> second screen.

I know that NavigationView -> NavigationLink about but I want to know how can I do the same but with Button(action {secondScreen})

thanks and bye! :D

Comment: so you want to navigate to the second screen with button or you want to do action in the second screen from the first screen ??

Comment: Look up "SwiftUI programatic navigation"

Comment: I want to navigate to the second screen from the first screen with button action

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64088346/change-view-without-navigation-link-swiftui

Comment: IMHO a NavigationLink pretty much IS a Button that leads to another screen

Answer (score 1):

You can bind navigation link to a button to achieve what you're looking for like this

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    // MARK: - PROPERTIES
    
    @State private var onSecondScreen: Bool = false
    
    // MARK: - BODY
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                // Your Button
                Button {
                    onSecondScreen = true
                } label: {
                    Text("Second Screen")
                }
                // NAVIGATION LINK
                NavigationLink(isActive: $onSecondScreen) {
                    Text("Second Screen")
                } label: {}
            }//: VSTACK
            
            
        }//: NAVIGATION
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```