# How can I reverse the slide transition for a SwiftUI animation?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, swiftui-animation

I'm working on a sequence of screens that should change on a button press and should slide in/out from right to left.
Everything is working nicely except the `.slide` transition makes it move in from the leading edge and move out to the trailing edge. (from left to right)
I want to reverse the transition animation direction without changing what trailing/leading is (at least not in the whole context of the app).

I tried changing the transition to `.move(edge: .trailing)` but then the views move in and out from the same direction.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    enum screens {
        case start, mid, final
    }
    @State var curScreen: screens = .start
    
    func changeScreen() {
        switch curScreen {
        case .start:
            curScreen = .mid
        case .mid:
            curScreen = .final
        case .final:
            return
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        switch curScreen {
        case .start:
            ScreenView(callback: changeScreen, text: "Start")
                .transition(.slide)
        case .mid:
            ScreenView(callback: changeScreen, text: "Mid")
                .transition(.slide)
        case .final:
            ScreenView(callback: {}, text: "Final")
                .transition(.slide)
        }
    }
}

struct ScreenView: View {
    let callback: () -> ()
    let text: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .padding()
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .onTapGesture {
                withAnimation(.default) {
                    callback()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63782921/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi yes it does! Thank you very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI how to have next and back animations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63782469/swiftui-how-to-have-next-and-back-animations)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

*[@Asperi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63782469/swiftui-how-to-have-next-and-back-animations/63782921#63782921) has already answered my question, but it didn't show up on google or stackoverflow when I searched for it, so here again for the algorithm:*

### How to reverse the slide transition in SwiftUI:

Taken from the Apple Developer Documentation:

```
static var slide: AnyTransition
// A transition that inserts by moving in from the leading edge, and removes by moving out towards the trailing edge.
```

Which can also be written as:

```
AnyTransition.asymmetric(
    insertion: .move(edge: .leading),
    removal: .move(edge: .trailing)
)
```

So to reverse the animation just flip `insertion` and `removal` and put that in your transition ViewModifier.

Since I needed to use it a few times I made an extension to `AnyTransition` so I can just call `.transition(.backslide)`

```
extension AnyTransition {
    static var backslide: AnyTransition {
        AnyTransition.asymmetric(
            insertion: .move(edge: .trailing),
            removal: .move(edge: .leading))}
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that works when going only forward. Thanks. However in my example a user have a choice to go Next or to go Back on the same screen. In this case I set backslide transition or simple slide depending on what user's action. And it doesn't work right after the change. Seems `removal` transition was set previously and can't be changed on the go. Added the same comment to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63782469/swiftui-how-to-have-next-and-back-animations# Maybe you have an idea how to deal with it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

for  ios 16

```
 Group {
                    switch viewModel.selectedTab {
                        case .travel:
                            TravelSearchForm(viewModel: viewModel)
                        case .cars:
                            CarsSearchForm(viewModel: viewModel.carsForm)
                        case .rooms:
                            RoomsSearchForm(viewModel: viewModel.roomsForm)
                    }
                }
                .transition(.dynamicSlide(forward: $viewModel.tabTransitionDirectionIsForward))
                .animation(.default, value: viewModel.selectedTab)

extension AnyTransition {

    struct SlideModifier: ViewModifier {
        let width: CGFloat
        @Binding var forward: Bool

        func body(content: Content) -> some View {
            content
                .offset(x: (forward ? 1 : -1) * width)
        }
    }

    static func dynamicSlide(forward: Binding<Bool>) -> AnyTransition {
        .asymmetric(
            insertion: .modifier(
                active: SlideModifier(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, forward: forward),
                identity: SlideModifier(width: 0, forward: .constant(true))
            ),

            removal: .modifier(
                active: SlideModifier(width: -UIScreen.main.bounds.width, forward: forward),
                identity: SlideModifier(width: 0, forward: .constant(true))
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `dinamicSlide`?

Comment: Heh, forgot to add the most interesting part ), fixed