# SwiftUI: How to create a custom SwiftUI Transition depending on a State Object?

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, transition

**Context**: I have encountered a problem while working with `SwiftUI Transitions`. I have a `FormView` containing 4 different `Sub-Forms`. When the User presses the `Next-Button`, the next `Sub-Form View` is presented with a `Transition` *(.move -> right to left)*.

I also have a `Back Button`. When the User presses this Button, the previous `Sub-Form View` is shown, currently with the same `Transition` *(.move -> right to left)*. However, I'd like to reverse the `Transition` in this case to *(.move -> left to right)*.

---

**Code**

```swift
enum FormStep {
    case step1, step2, step3, step4
}

struct CustomForm: View  {
    @State private var step: FormStep = .step1

    var body: some View {
        // This Button will change the step State to the previous step
        Button(action: { withAnimation { previousStep() } } { Text("Previous") }

        // This is the Right to Left Transition applied to subForm
        subForm
            .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .trailing), removal: .move(edge: .leading)))

        // This Button will change the step State to the next step
        Button(action: { withAnimation { nextStep() } } { Text("Next") }
    }

    @ViewBuilder private var subForm: some View {
        switch medicationFormVM.step {
        case .step1: StepOneSubForm()
        case .step2: StepTwoSubForm()
        case .step3: StepThreeSubForm()
        case .step4: StepFourSubForm()
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Question:** As you can see, not matter whether you navigate back or forth, the `Transition` will always be `right to left`. How can I achieve my goal of changing the `Transition` depending on which `Button` got pressed?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63782921/12299030?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an approach for you:

```
enum FormTransition {
    case next, back
    var value: AnyTransition {
        switch self {
        case .next:
            return AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .trailing), removal: .move(edge: .leading))
        case .back:
            return AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .leading), removal: .move(edge: .trailing))
        }
    }
}

struct CustomForm: View  {
    
    @State private var step: FormStep = .step1
    @State private var transition: AnyTransition = FormTransition.next.value
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Button(action: { transition = FormTransition.back.value; withAnimation { previousStep() } } { Text("Previous") })
        
        subForm
            .transition(transition)
        
        Button(action: { transition = FormTransition.next.value; withAnimation { nextStep() } } { Text("Next") })
    }
    
}
```

Comment: This would have a glitch if you ever wanted to change transition type: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77663398/iterating-type-of-assymetric-transition-causes-glitch